# Crash in Swift app after tapping a button

Tags: ios, swift

I know this is silly but I'm having a bit of a trouble shooting and need help. I created a log out button to log users out of the account but when touching the log out button I get an error showing this

Code :

```
@IBAction func logout_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            //try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
        } catch
            let logoutError {
                print(logoutError)
        }
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Start", bundle: nil)
        let signInVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewController")
        self.present(signInVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

[image: my Error]

[image: Logout btoon]

Is there a way to fix this problem? Thanks to anyone helping.

Comment: show me your code

Comment: }
    @IBAction func logout_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
        } catch let logoutError {
            print(logoutError)
        }
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Start", bundle: nil)
        let signInVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewController")
        self.present(signInVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

Comment: @Joseph Do not post code in comments. Please [edit] your question with all relevant code and complete error messages.

Comment: can you please add the code here

Comment: To find out this type of crash .enable exception breakpoint. follow this to enable - > project navigator -> go to 7th option (breakpoint navigation ) -> in   left bottom you will see plus (+).click on this exception breakpoint .

Comment: Give breakpoint and first check whether the method is calling or not.. If not then it is a connection issue. If the method get called, then debug line by line and check after which line its crashing. The error what you have given is a generic error, so the exact reason you can analyse after proper debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, Delete your button outlet and reconnect with your button outlet and action . it will solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

This is a common error in Swift. Most likley there isnt anythingh wrong with the logout button or anythingh else around it but with your executed code after the button is pressed.

Maybe the "connection" between your execution method and the button is also corrupt.